# Django/DRF: How can I get more than one slug_field from serializers.SlugRelatedField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer to populate an AJAX table that looks something like this:

```
class BookSerializer(seralizers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field="name"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            "name",
            "author",
            "slug"
        )
```

`author` can contain any number of authors, which is why I need to handle it this way. Currently I can print out the name of the book and link it with its slug. I also get a list of author names rather than the IDs.

My question is how I can *also* get the slugs for each author page? I would like to link each author to its own page, but using something like `author.slug` doesn't work, nor did adding this:

```
    author_slugs = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name="slug"
    )
```

Then I added author_slugs to fields -- this threw an error that author_slugs is not a valid field in the Book model. Is there a way to access more than field for each author?

Comment: Maybe you can try adding a property `author_slugs` to your model to get around the the error you mentioned? I haven't tried it myself maybe it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a [nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). Try

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = (
            'name',
            'page',
        )

class BookSerializer(seralizers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            "name",
            "author",
            "slug"
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets the data into my API! But how do I print it? When I try to loop through `book.author.name` and `book.author.page` it returns an error. I've also tried `book.author["name"]` and `book.author["page"]` with no luck. Just printing book.author prints `[Object object]` for each author for the book.

Comment: Nevermind -- figured it out. For anyone struggling in the future, I needed to still loop through just `book.author`, then within the loop access `a.name` and `a.page` (`a` in this case being the alias assigned to each iteration of my loop).

Answer (score 3):

It will absolutely throw an error because `author_slugs` is not a valid attribute on **Book Model**.

In this case if you want to rename a specific value in the model, and map it to your serializer you can use the `source` attribute to tell the serializer from where it should get the value from the model.

This should look like this:

```
...
author_slugs = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name="slug",
        source='author', # or whatever is the name of the related field in your model.
)
...
```

Comment: its a actual solution which i was looking.